# Smooth Transition when clicking card

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on recreating the functionality of this [website](https://skiff.com/) where when you click on the card and that card moves to the front.

I have managed to get this functionality working here as shown in the code below, but how would I get that slow smooth animation that takes place when the cards swap? Is this something that can be done using CSS, having said that I am leaning toward JS being the right tool to solve this animation issue

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
const parent = document.querySelector(".container");


Array.from(boxes).map((box, index) => {
  box.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let copy = [...boxes];
    let nw = Array.from(boxes).slice(index);
    copy.splice(index);

    let arr = [...nw, ...copy];

    arr.map((ar) => {
      parent.append(ar);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 490px;
}

.container div:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 4;
  transform: translateY(90px);
}
.container div:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translateY(0px) translateZ(-70px);
}
.container div:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateY(-90px) translateZ(-140px);
}
.container div:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(-180px) translateZ(-210px);
}

#red {
  background: red;
}

#black {
  background: black;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
}
#green {
  background: green;
}

.container div {
  margin-top: 0px;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.container div:hover {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class=container>
    <div class=box id=red></div>
    <div class=box id=black></div>
    <div class=box id=blue></div>
    <div class=box id=green></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Because of the way you are remapping your z-index, placing a transition is not easily solved on the motion from a lower index to the top index. You may want to use the event.target to add some kind of fade to the event and the top level element before you fire the switching of the z-index, add a setTimeout or async function that correlates with your initial fade animation, also run a final fade in method to fade the top level element and previous event.target element.

Comment: Ahh ok so part of the issue is that I am using css to apply the z-index and transform properties, should these styling changes be done dynamically using JavaScript?

Comment: Well think about the time line of the click, once you click, fade the clicked element and the top level element before moving it. Then once that fade is complete run the code snippit that switches the index and also bring the fade back in for both elements. This would allow you to give the illusion of an animation. As it is now, the `transform` will not animate using a transition as it is just being switched, I am not sure if it is a limitation of transform/transitioning with respect to `translateZ` or not as I did not do any in depth testing there, but it is what I suspect.